# Energy Density is expressed in Liters, Liters of What?

Tags: conventions, batteries, si-units, volume

When looking at energy density of batteries it is often expressed as Wh/L. For instance, Wikipedia says Lithium Ion batteries have a density of 250–693 W·h/L. Liters is supposed to express the volume but the volume depends on the density of the substance. So liters of what? Water?

Comment: "The volume depends on the density of the substance." This might be where the misunderstanding is coming from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volume is volume. A (large) battery that is a cube 10 cm on a side has a volume of 1 liter regardless of what it is made of, or what density it has.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting confused by the word "density".

The actual use of "density" refers to *any* quantity measured relative to a *unit volume*.  What we often call "density" actually means *mass density*, or *mass per unit volume*.  That is likely why you are associating mass with density.

When they say "energy density" though, they are referring to *energy per unit volume*; and it isn't really related to mass density; besides that they are both quantities expressed per unit volume.

Answer (score 0):

A liter is simply a unit of volume equal to 1000 cm$^3$. It could be a volume of anything (air, water, a solid). Technology is trying to pack more energy into a smaller volume of a battery to save space.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, the energy density is expressed in liters of battery.

Lithium Ion batteries have a density of 250–693 W·h/L of battery.